# Hyperref pdfborder box not appearing in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, links

I want hyperref to box my links, not colour them but I can't make it work after trying loads of different things.

Current status is:

```
\usepackage[pdfborder]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=false,
    citebordercolor=[rgb]{1,0,0},
    linkbordercolor=[rgb]{1,0,0},
    linktocpage=true
  }
```

The page number is clickable but it doesn't have the highlighted box that I was hoping for.
In case it makes a difference, I'm using `\documentclass[english, PhD, twoside]{sapthesis}`

Comment: as you didn't provide a complete example I can't test. But it can depend on the pdf viewer if you see a border, so check with adobe reader.

Comment: Thank you, I was using overleaf but in Preview it shows up.